# Swift 2.0: can not pass generic as a parameter

Tags: swift, generics

Why is this not working(even though the Container conforms to Unique protocol.) and how would the best workaround looks like?

```
protocol Unique {
    var uniqueId: String {get}
}

struct Container <T>: Unique {
    typealias UnderlyingObject = T
    var object: UnderlyingObject
    var uniqueId: String
}

func myFunc(protocolClosure: (Unique, Unique) -> Unique) {
    print("...")
}

func problemStartsHere<T,S,U>(paramClosure: (Container<T>, Container<S>) -> Container<U>) {
    myFunc(paramClosure)
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is an issue with generic type covariance/contravariance, however I'm not a Swift user so I cannot be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler shows this warning for a reason: `myFunc` expects a closure that works for any kind of `Unique` not just `Container<T>`.

You should use a generic version of the function instead:

```
func myFunc<A: Unique, B: Unique, C: Unique>(protocolClosure: (A, B) -> C) {
    print("...")
}
```

EDIT: Suppose you wanted to call your function `problemStartsHere` like this:

```
problemStartsHere { (c1: Container<Int>, c2: Container<Int>) -> Container<Int> in
    print(c1.object, c2.object)
    return c1
}
```

Notice that the function uses the `Container`-specific property `object`. Not how exactly should the compiler create a closure that works on any `Unique`? It can't work like this, because it doesn't make sense, such a function cannot work on any `Unique`.

Comment: The reason seems illogical to me. Any Container is already Unique so why not accept it?

Comment: @purrrminator Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is one of variance, though not quite the variance you're looking for. Since you're passing a closure, you're really trying to make the method signature itself match, rather than the value passed into or return from of the method itself. This could raise problems if, say, `myFunc` tried invoking the closure using a parameter of a type other than `Container<T>` - and since it expects any `Unique` to be acceptable for that invocation, it would compile just fine.

Comment: The problem with answering that portion of the question, @purrrminator, is that I do not and have never programmed in Swift, but know enough about it's basis on C# mechanics to know this much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the return value. While you can pass any `Container<...>` to `Unique` parameter, the return value of type `Unique` can't be cast to `Container<...>`. That's why the closure type `(Container<...>, Container<...>) -> Container<...>` cannot be cast to `(Unique, Unique) -> Unique`.